# What is the domain of convergence of this power series $\sum_{n\ge1}{{(\cos{\frac{1}{n}})^{\frac{n^2+2}{n+2}}x^n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

We have this power series $$\sum_{n\ge1}{{(\cos{\frac{1}{n}})^{\frac{n^2+2}{n+2}}x^n}}$$
How do I calculate the radius? I have tryed both criteria(root one and ratio one) in both I get something with a limit that i dont know to calculate.

Comment: Have you tried applying the root test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that $\sqrt[n]{\cos^{(n^2+2)/(n+2)}(1/n)}=\cos^{\frac{n^2+2}{n^2+2n}}(1/n)$.  Then, we have

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\cos^{(n^2+2)/(n+2)}(1/n)x^n\right|}=|x|$$

Now, apply the root test.

Comment: So ${|x|>1}$ (to converge) so ${-1<x<1}$? But why $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\cos^{(n^2+2)/(n+2)}(1/n)x^n\right|}=|x|$$, I mean $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\cos^{(n^2+2)/(n+2)}(1/n)x^n\right|}=\lim_{n\to \infty}|x|\sqrt[n]{\left|\cos^{(n^2+2)/(n+2)}(1/n)\right|}$, so what happens with that $\sqrt[n]{\cos^{(n^2+2)/(n+2)}(1/n)}$ ? Why does his limit goes to 1?

Comment: Was the hint not enough?  Look at the first part again; $1^1=1$.

Comment: Ok, my bad I've seen wrong I thought that you did nothing to that $\cos$. Thx, now I understand.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.